# programmically give input to yeoman cmd for CI/CD tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yeoman

when we run the yeoman it is asking to add input one by one, is there anyway to give all input one go ? or programically?

for Example :

[yo azuresfguest](https://github.com/microsoft/generator-azuresfguest)

it is asking to add 5 inputs, which i want to give one time, so i can run in CI/CD system

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a general way, unfortunately. The specific generator would need to allow it.

I think it is deserving of a feature request on the Yeoman project, which I've [logged here](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/756).

As a cumbersome workaround, you can create your own generator which re-uses an existing generator. The TypeScript code below gives an example; I'm using this approach to automate my CI process.

Add option to constructor:

```
  constructor(args: string, opts: Generator.GeneratorOptions) {
      super(args, opts);
      ...
      this.option("prompts-json-file", {
          type: String,
          default: undefined,
          description: "Skips prompting; uses file contents. Useful for automation",
      });
  }
```

Use the option:

```
async prompting() {
  if (this.options["prompts-json-file"] !== undefined) {
      this.answers = new Answers(JSON.parse(
              fs.readFileSync(this.options["prompts-json-file"]).toString()
      ));
  }
  else {
    this.answers = ...
  }
```

}

Unfortunately this does bypass prompt validation so you'd need to separately ensure your file contains valid values.

Using it is relatively simple:

```
yo my-generator --prompts-json-file ./prompts.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be accomplished using Yeomans storage API and a `.yo-rc.json` file:
https://yeoman.io/authoring/storage.html

I used to use a self defined option to make that optional similar to the approach from @BjornO

```
constructor(args, opts) {
  super(args, opts);

  // This method adds support for a `--yo-rc` flag
  this.option('yo-rc', {
    desc: 'Read and apply options from .yo-rc.json and skip prompting',
    type: Boolean,
    defaults: false
  });
}

initializing() {
  this.skipPrompts = false;

  if (this.options['yo-rc']) {
    const config = this.config.getAll();

    this.log(
      'Read and applied the following config from ' +
        chalk.yellow('.yo-rc.json:\n')
    );
    this.log(config);
    this.log('\n');

    this.templateProps = {
      projectName: config.projectName,
    };
    this.skipPrompts = true;
  }
}

prompting() {
  if (!this.skipPrompts) {
    // Have Yeoman greet the user.
    this.log(
      yosay(
        `Yo, welcome to the ${superb()} ${chalk.yellow(
          'Baumeister'
        )} generator!`
      )
    );

    const prompts = [
      {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'projectName',
        message: 'What’s the name of your project?',
        // Default to current folder name
        default: _s.titleize(this.appname)
      }
    ];

    return this.prompt(prompts).then(props => {
      this.templateProps = {
        projectName: props.projectName
      };
    });
  }
}
```

See https://github.com/micromata/generator-baumeister/blob/master/app/index.js#L20-L69 for the whole generator code and [https://github.com/micromata/generator-baumeister/blob/master/\_\_tests__/yo-rc.json](https://github.com/micromata/generator-baumeister/blob/master/%5C_%5C_tests__/yo-rc.json) for the corresponding `.yo-rc.json` file.